# Magnetically shielding an actuator

Tags: magnetics

We need to magnetically shield a solenoid that activates this valve (shown below)

[image]

Just slipping a mild steel cap over the end does not do the job, nor appears to have any screening effect at all. Any suggestions for a practical way of doing this? Or any explanation of why a mild steel cap is not working?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of magnetic field are you trying to shield against? I don´t imagine it´s any kind of high frequency RF or similar, but to be effective in that case, the shield would need to be earthed.

For shielding against a 'normal' magnetic field, you´d need a bit more than just a mild steel cap. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Magnetic_shielding).

Comment: Sorry - I want to stop the magnetic field of the actuator affecting other magnetically sensitive components. In this case, a microbalance armature.

Comment: I suspect that the metal cap is saturating. Going to try a mu metal cap